# upsampling timeseries from daily to hourly

Tags: pandas, interpolation, resampling

I am using data below, which is saved in a CSV file, and trying to convert it to hourly using linear interpolation. However, not successful.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('d:/Python/resampling/FairyLake.csv')
df[ 'Date' ] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date').resample('M').interpolate()
print(df)
```

Data

```
Date,Discharge
1/3/2008,0.05865
1/4/2008,0.105812
1/5/2008,0.191388
1/6/2008,0.315378
1/7/2008,0.477782
1/8/2008,0.6786
1/9/2008,0.917832
1/10/2008,0.783875701
1/11/2008,0.65678957
1/12/2008,0.545651187
1/13/2008,0.44222808
1/14/2008,0.353907613
1/15/2008,0.27414753
```

**Results**

```
 Date  Discharge
0  2008-01-03   0.058650
1  2008-01-04   0.105812
2  2008-01-05   0.191388
3  2008-01-06   0.315378
4  2008-01-07   0.477782
5  2008-01-08   0.678600
6  2008-01-09   0.917832
7  2008-01-10   0.783876
8  2008-01-11   0.656790
9  2008-01-12   0.545651
10 2008-01-13   0.442228
11 2008-01-14   0.353908
12 2008-01-15   0.274148
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. [`resample interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.interpolate.html#pandas-core-resample-resampler-interpolate) should be hourly (`H`)
2. results need to be assigned back `df = ...`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date').resample('H').interpolate()
```

`df`:

```
                     Discharge
Date                          
2008-01-03 00:00:00   0.058650
2008-01-03 01:00:00   0.060615
2008-01-03 02:00:00   0.062580
2008-01-03 03:00:00   0.064545
2008-01-03 04:00:00   0.066510
...                        ...
2008-01-14 20:00:00   0.287441
2008-01-14 21:00:00   0.284118
2008-01-14 22:00:00   0.280794
2008-01-14 23:00:00   0.277471
2008-01-15 00:00:00   0.274148
```